# MySQL fetch inactive user for n amount of days from created day

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch users that were inactive for N days from created date. I have dates stored in timestamp. I tried to pull it like that

```
SELECT name, created, accessed 
FROM users 
WHERE accessed >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

but it's not really working for me. I can't figure out how to build query to get inactive users that weren't active for N days from `created`.

Comment: Show your ddl, sample data and expected output

Comment: Typo? `WHERE AND` the `AND` is wrong there

Comment: Typo. Ill edit and add extra

Comment: Rather than comparing NOW() and _accessed_, shouldn't you be comparing _created_ and _accessed_?

Comment: try 'CURDATE( )' instead of 'DATE(NOW()' like this time >= (CURDATE( ) - INTERVAL 3 DAY)

Comment: @Jens Sample data is not necessary here. I have just simple `users` table. Thats has `name`, `created`, `accessed` columns.

Comment: @SloanThrasher thats what I can't figure out how to construct

Comment: Please don't tell us what is and isn't necessary

Comment: @strawberry offtopic comment. Also, I didnt mean to offend anyone or be rude

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Show users where last access was longer then 3 days ago:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    created, 
    accessed 
FROM users 
WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), accessed)) > 3
```

Comment: The OP wants to compare the created date to the accessed date in spite of the example SQL in the question.

Comment: Now I'm confused: Use `timestampdiff(DAY, created, accessed)` to get diff between creation and last access. Use `timestampdiff(DAY, accessed, NOW())` to get diff between last access and now. Then you can compare this value to `N` in the `Where`-Part

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_ADD()` to get inactive users by adding the **N** days to `created` column and then matching with `accessed` column. The example may be as:

```
SELECT name, created, accessed 
FROM users 
WHERE accessed >= DATE_ADD(created, INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

`DATE_SUB()` uses to add time,days,years etc in specified date formated in timestamp.

> For further study on this function please see here
>   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you can do here is

```
SELECT * from users where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),accessed) > 3
```

CURDATE() - Current Date

accessed  - last time account was accessed

3         - Difference of days.

Hope it Helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing NOW() with the column `created`. That way you are looking for users where accessed is more than the created date plus 3 days.

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    created, 
    accessed 
FROM users 
WHERE accessed >= DATE(created + INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```